# Key-Value Store that is tolerant of writes and deletes

Tags: database-design, hashtable, bigdata, key-value-store

## Problem

Having trouble finding a Key-Value store that is tolerant of writes and deletes.

## Details

Need a good key-value store to use for storing very large hash tables. These hash tables are used as indexes and are very "active". Very many deletes and writes are executed against them.

Currently, we are storing these hash tables in a large (128gb RAM) Redis server. Redis performs great. But this is not surprising considering Redis stores everything in RAM. Other databases that we have tried, such as Cassandra and MongoDB suffer huge performance hits when writes and especially deletes become too heavy.

We speculate that there should be a database out there that will perform well using SSDs (solid state drives) instead of relying on RAM to contain the entirety of the data.

This is our criteria:

- Tolerant of heavy writes and deletes
- Performs well using SSDs instead of containing everything in RAM (like Redis)
- Doesn't need a lot of "search features" such as creating ordered indexes. Really only needs to `GET` and `SET` by key.

Have been searching around, but most information I come across seems to focus mostly on features (clusterable, map-reduce, etc...). There are some references to performance such as "low-latency", which I would expect from a key value store. I was not able to turn up much by searching with terms such as "delete tolerant key value store".

## Question

- How should I go about finding the right database?
- Are there any "key" terms I should be searching for? (such as "low latency")
- Are there classes of databases that fit this use case to a greater or lesser degree?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Hey Kermit, this question is asking for help with a strategy on the search for the right database. It is not asking for specific recommendations. For example, what key terms should I be searching for? Are there classes of databases that fit this use case to a greater or lesser degree? I am familiar with the term "low-latency" but I'm not sure what term applies to a database that is delete tolerant.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map)

Pros

- persisted to disk. designed for heavy write rates such as high ticking market data such as options Opera feed.
- typical latency around 1 micro-second for small entries. read and write.
- much faster than redis. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/sharedhashmap-vs-redis.html About 2 orders of magnitude.
- supports write rates of over 20 million per second with data sets of 500 GB on a 128 GB machine (something I regularly test) with SSD storage.
- supports persistence of 500 million keys-values on a 128 GB machine.
- Apache 2.0 OSS
- GC free design. i.e. can be used without creating any garbage.

Cons

- only supports Java 7+
- Tested to 2.5 billion entries on a 128 GB machine but has inconsistent performance at this point and above. e.g. write rates drop from 26 million per second to 1.3 million per second.

Chronicle Map doesn't have tombstones or compaction.  Once it grows to a particular size, it doesn't shrink disk usage, though it attempts to reuse deleted entries in an efficient manner.

More links

- [What is Chronicle Map?](http://openhft.net/products/chronicle-map/)
- [OpenJDK and HashMap …. Safely Teaching an Old Dog New (Off-Heap!) Tricks](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Open-JDK-and-HashMap-Off-Heap)

Answer (score 0):

Consider RocksDb http://rocksdb.org

Its a simple key-value store and is optimised for SSDs.

They used a database of 800 GB in their benchmarks:
https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Performance-Benchmarks